# Is there a way of running create-react-app offline with local files?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Our corporate security policy is set up where devs need to use a separate account for running non-whitelisted programs, but these accounts have no access to the internet so it cannot download any files when I attempt to run create-react-app.

Is it possible to download the necessary files beforehand with my normal account which does have internet access and then use those files to run create-react-app offline?

Answer (score 2):

While you create the app it will have to download the installation packages. Maybe if you spin up your own registry locally with caching, then install the packages once, cache them and then use the cache. I am wondering how to develop in an environment that restrictive?

On the other side you could just clone the create-react-app repository, then npm link the repo globally and you can execute with the app with all files offline. The installation step will not work then I propose.